# windows 7 account Lockout when network share

Tags: windows-7, networking, user-accounts, shared-folders

A brief idea of the machine setup:
Two Win7 Pro machines A and B, with Account lockout threshold policy set to 3 attempts. 
Both the machines have same local user account(same user name) logged in but has different passwords. 

My use case:

Access a shared folder of machine B from machine A. (\\serverA)

I get an error message as the referenced account is locked out. No dialog box for asking credentials is asked

 May be because the accesing the share retries 3 times and the account gets locked out. 

 if the threshold is set to 4 I get the dialog box for credentials 

 
 if any has faced this issue? OR how can I disable the feature of auto login during access if there are similar accounts?

Comment: These local accounts or domain accounts.  If they are local accounts they are actually entirely different users

Comment: These are local accounts, but no idea why they are accessed from other machine.

Comment: If they are local accounts then they cannot be accessed from another machine and despite them using the same username they are actually unique users ( because of their unique id ).